# How did a process with an url as a name executed at my macos?

Tags: macos, security, memory, google-chrome

Is it some sort of chrome malfunction? - The process seems inactive, it has "http://www.imore.com/, ..." as the name, with a lego-like plugin icon, a default icon

I suspect it might have been an orphaned chrome-flash process, yet I haven't visited imore.com, which makes the situation very suspicious

(It's using 145MB Ram, it seems to be inactive with no disk/network/cpu operations)

Any ideas? (I don't have any chrome extensions/plugins, I also don't execute any web content)

---

Edit: After trying to kill the process, I see that it's a "Spotlight Web Content", haven't killed it yet to inspect the issue further

---

It seems to be a webkit process, I just hope it was from the spotlight, I disabled several spotlight features after the issue, here are ps/top info about the process:

58056 ??         3:41.21 /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A

58056  com.apple.We 0.0  03:41.21 21    0    238   141M   0B     4744K  58056 1     sleeping *0[12383]       0.00000 0.00000    501  479108    777

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that but I'm the user of the process

Comment: Are you logged in to the imore website?

Comment: No I have never heard of the site before, the only possible explanation I could come up with is: The spotlight might have rendered something from imore.com, and left the process orphaned, I don't recall this happening either, but might have happenned

Comment: where do you see that process? in Activity Monitor ?

Comment: Yes, updated the question with more info now

Comment: not seen it in Chrome, but a blue 'Lego brick' is usually 'wrong type of Flash'

Comment: check this post out. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167332/process-named-after-website-executing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Eric - haven't noticed this issue myself after disabling some of the Spotlight features, I don't use Safari