# Process named after website executing?

Tags: spotlight, macos

While looking at Activity Monitor processes, I noticed a process whose name started with "http://".

Shortly after observing and screenshoting the process disappeared.  This morning, it briefly re-appeared and then died.

lsof and dtracte indicate the process is looking at standard system libraries, one of which is /private/var/db/mds/messages/se_SecurityMessages.

Any ideas on:

1. Whether this is a normal process?
2. How to find where and how it's launched? (Mac doesnt have /proc...?)
3. How to investigate what its doing?

Comment: dtruss shows extremely minimal activity, lots of workq_kernreturn , kevent64, etc

Comment: Alright, I never use Safari.  But I fired it up to go the mac developer forums.  When I visit idmsa.apple.com, I see a named process for that popup in Activity Monitor.  Say what?

Comment: If I open tabs for other webpages, they also spin up processes with names corresponding to the webpage.  But since I've never visited http://mall... , and I wasn't running safari at the time, why this process?

Comment: I noticed the same when i've visited asw.apple.com yesterday. Perhaps it is a process the browsers start to display the markup language?

Comment: I think Safari is spinning off a separate process for each webpage.  Activity Monitor is helpfully digging down into it to pull out the name of the webpage.

Comment: Indeed, strange thing is that when I open activity Monitor now, I see apple.stackexchange.com, but also websites I visited last week

Comment: It's awesome to work with undocumented OS features

Comment: Perhaps this will give you some more information about the processes in Activity Monitor that safari uses: http://www.macissues.com/2014/10/11/determine-which-os-x-process-ids-are-for-your-safari-windows/#more-2231

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Normal in the way Safari now operates.

Each process is part of Safari sandboxing.

If you go to the View menu in Activity Monitor and down to the 'All Processes Hierarchically'

[image]

You will see that they all gathered and are owned by Safari.

[image]

Also this is a known feature: [apple.com/safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/)

> Sandboxing for websites.
>
> Sandboxing provides built-in protection against malicious code and
> malware by restricting what websites can do. And because Safari runs
> web pages in separate processes, any harmful code you come across in
> one page is confined to a single browser tab, so it can’t crash the
> whole browser or access your data.

---